# How do you check if a button component is present in UI in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity and was wondering if it was possible to check if a button component in present in the scene, this is like a UI test.

I am trying to do this using the Unity UI Test Automation tool.

Comment: Something like `GameObject.activeInHierarchy;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While zyonneo answer is correct, `GameObject.Find` can be slow if there is a lot of gameObjects.

What I would do instead is looking for the button component in the canvas children. For this you need a reference to the parent canvas of your button.

```
public GameObject MyCanvas;

void Start(){
    if(MyCanvas.GetComponentInChildren<Button>() != null){
         Debug.Log("Button found");
    else {
         Debug.Log("Button not found");
    }
}
```

If you want more information about what is the most efficient way to find a gameObject, I recommend you to read [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/most-efficient-way-to-find-a-gameobject.412281/) on Unity Formus.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply! Can these be implemented as UI tests? That's what I am looking for. @AntoineThiry

Comment: You are welcome, I don't know a lot about UI Tests so you should try it, if you have access to ``UnityEngine`` namespace then you should be able to use this :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the code where you want to check whether the button is present in Hierarchy.If you have added the button in the canvas you can find using the below code.Just type the exact name of the button.

By default when you add a button it will have the name "Button" so search with that parameter.Here I am adding a button by right clicking and then renaming it into "Btn01"

```
if(GameObject.Find("Btn01")!= null)
    {
        Debug.Log("Button is Present in Hierarchy");

    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Button Not Present");

    }
```

Comment: This doesn't return true if the button component is present in the UI in unity, only if you have a GameObject named `Btn01`.  `https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html` would be a better test case.